# Using Core Animation/CALayer for simple layered painting

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer

I would like to create a custom NSView that takes a layered approach to painting. I imagine the majority of the layers would be the same width and height as the backing view.

Is it appropriate to use the Core Animation classes like CALayer for this task, even though I don't expect to need much animation? Is there a more appropriate approach?

To clarify, the view is not meant to be like a canvas in a Photoshop-like application. It more of a data display that should allow for user interaction (selecting, moving, scrolling, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's display and layout you're after, I'd say that a CALayer-based architecture is a good choice.  For the open source [Core Plot framework](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/), we construct all of our graphs and plot elements out of CALayers, and organize them in a regular hierarchy.  CALayers are lightweight and use almost identical APIs between Mac and iPhone.  They can even be made to respond to touch or mouse events.

For another example of a CALayer-based user interface, [my iPhone application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/picubed)'s entire equation entry interface is composed of CALayers, including the menu that slides up from below.  Performance is slightly better than that of my previous UIView-based implementation, but the same code also works within my preliminary desktop version of the application.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at Core Plot for some guidance!

Answer (score 2):

For a drawing program, I would imagine it would be important to hold a buffer of the bitmap data. The only issue with using a `CALayer` is that the `contents` property is a `CGImageRef`. To turn that back into a graphics context for doing further drawing can be a bit of a pain. You'd have to initialize a new context, draw the bitmap data into it, then do whatever drawing operations you wanted to do, and finally turn that back into a `CGImageRef`. You probably wouldn't be able to avoid doing a number of pretty large memory allocations, which is virtually guaranteed to slow your program way down.

I would consider holding an off-screen buffer for each layer. Take a look at the Quartz `CGLayerRef` object. I think it probably does what you want to do: it's an off-screen buffer that holds things you might want to draw repeatedly. You can also quickly get a `CGContextRef` whenever you need it so you can do additional drawing. And you can always use that `CGContextRef` with `NSGraphicsContext` if you want to use Cocoa drawing methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "drawing program", but to clarify, the view is not meant to be like a canvas in a Photoshop-like application. It more of a data display that should allow for user interaction (selecting, moving, scrolling, etc.)

Comment: Then it depends on whether what you're drawing can be easily and quickly redrawn as needed, or whether that's a time-consuming operation. In the first case, Core Animation layers would work just fine. CGLayers work better as a cache for things that are expensive to redraw.